# Select top N elements of related objects

Tags: java, c#, algorithm, recursion

I have a class `Product` to hold a specific instance of a given product.
This class has a list of related products that are similar to main product.

```
class Product
{
    public string Name;
    public double Rating;
    public List<Product> RelatedProducts;
    //...
    public List<Product> GetTopRelatedProducts(int N)
    {
        // How to implement this method
        // What I did so far(Bad code)
        //     1- INFINITE RECURSION
        //     2- Can not remember visited objects
        var myList = new List<Product>();
        foreach(Product prod in RelatedProducts)
        {
             myList.AddRange(prod.GetTopRelatedProducts(N));
        }
        return myList.Distinct().OrderByDescending(x => x.Rating).Take(N).ToList();
    }
}
```

I want to define a method within `Product` class to get top `N` (best rated) related products. This method should take into consideration that elements in `RelatedProducts` list are of type `Product` and they also have their own `RelatedProducts` list. So I should keep navigating nested object until all related products were reached and after that, take the top N product. 
I mean, the solution would not be simply `this.RelatedProducts.OrderByDescending(x => x.Rating).Take(N);`

One more thing to keep in mind: **Two products can be mutually related**. Which means a product **A** can belong to `RelatedProducts` list of a product **B** and **B** also can belong to `RelatedProducts` list of product **A**.

Any suggestion how to solve this issue in optimal way?

Imagine, I have millions of products to maintain. How can I navigate all related products recursively and recognize already visited ones?

I tagged this as both C# and Java, as the same logic could be applied to both languages

Comment: Try implementing *some* solution that works; if it isn't fast enough, then you can look into optimizing it.  But so far, you haven't shown *any* effort at solving this.

Comment: Are you going a fixed level deep on your "recursion", presumably a related product of a related product of a related product may not be related to the original product.

If so I think you are on the right route and just union the differing depths together.

Comment: @ScottHunter I added what I did so far. But is not a solution as it will end up in INFINITE RECURSION

Comment: Can you rely on reference equality for `Product` instances?

Comment: @IvanStoev for ease of code, we can rely on reference equality

Comment: So as Ivan Stoev has already asked, what do you expect from your bounty? What's wrong with already suggested answers?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Imagine, I have millions of products to maintain. How can I navigate all related products recursively and recognize already visited ones?

It doesn't need to be recursive. Explicit `Stack` or `Queue` can serve the navigating part. For collecting the result a `HashSet` can be used instead of `List`. It would serve two purposes - to allow you to skip the already visited elements and also eliminate the need of `Distinct` at the end.

Here is a sample `Queue` based implementation:

```
public List<Product> GetTopRelatedProducts(int N)
{
    var relatedSet = new HashSet<Product>();
    var relatedListQueue = new Queue<List<Product>>();
    if (RelatedProducts != null && RelatedProducts.Count > 0)
        relatedListQueue.Enqueue(RelatedProducts);
    while (relatedListQueue.Count > 0)
    {
        var relatedList = relatedListQueue.Dequeue();
        foreach (var product in relatedList)
        {
            if (product != this && relatedSet.Add(product) && product.RelatedProducts != null && product.RelatedProducts.Count > 0)
                relatedListQueue.Enqueue(product.RelatedProducts);
        }
    }
    return relatedSet.OrderByDescending(x => x.Rating).Take(N).ToList();
}
```

**Update:** For completeness, here are the other possible implementations of the related set collecting part:

*With explicit `Stack`:*

```
public List<Product> GetTopRelatedProducts(int N)
{
    if (RelatedProducts == null || RelatedProducts.Count == 0)
        return new List<Product>();
    var relatedSet = new HashSet<Product>();
    var pendingStack = new Stack<List<Product>.Enumerator>();
    var relatedList = RelatedProducts.GetEnumerator(); 
    while (true)
    {
        while (relatedList.MoveNext())
        {
            var product = relatedList.Current;
            if (product != this && relatedSet.Add(product) && product.RelatedProducts != null && product.RelatedProducts.Count > 0)
            {
                pendingStack.Push(relatedList);
                relatedList = product.RelatedProducts.GetEnumerator();
            }
        }
        if (pendingStack.Count == 0) break;
        relatedList = pendingStack.Pop();
    } 
    return relatedSet.OrderByDescending(x => x.Rating).Take(N).ToList();
}
```

Although a bit more verbose than the explicit `Queue` based implementation, this method has less space requirements - **O(height)** where `height` is the maximum depth.

The benefit of both iterative implementations is that of course they can handle much bigger depth than the recursive solutions which can lead to `StackOverflowExpection`. But if the depth is not expected to be so big and you prefer recursion, then here are a couple recursive implementations (all they need to have access to the `relatedSet` and `this`):

*With classic private recursive method:*

```
public List<Product> GetTopRelatedProducts(int N)
{
    var relatedSet = new HashSet<Product>();
    GetRelatedProducts(this, relatedSet);
    return relatedSet.OrderByDescending(x => x.Rating).Take(N).ToList();
}

private void GetRelatedProducts(Product product, HashSet<Product> relatedSet)
{
    if (product.RelatedProducts == null) return;
    foreach (var item in product.RelatedProducts)
        if (item != this && relatedSet.Add(item))
            GetRelatedProducts(item, relatedSet);
}
```

*With recursive lambda:*

```
public List<Product> GetTopRelatedProductsD(int N)
{
    var relatedSet = new HashSet<Product>();
    Action<Product> GetRelatedProducts = null;
    GetRelatedProducts = product =>
    {
        if (product.RelatedProducts == null) return;
        foreach (var item in product.RelatedProducts)
            if (item != this && relatedSet.Add(item))
                GetRelatedProducts(item);
    };
    GetRelatedProducts(this);
    return relatedSet.OrderByDescending(x => x.Rating).Take(N).ToList();
}
```

*Last, but not least, with the latest C# 7.0 addition - recursive [local function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/csharp-7#local-functions):*

```
public List<Product> GetTopRelatedProducts(int N)
{
    var relatedSet = new HashSet<Product>();
    GetRelatedProducts(this);
    return relatedSet.OrderByDescending(x => x.Rating).Take(N).ToList();

    void GetRelatedProducts(Product product)
    {
        if (product.RelatedProducts == null) return;
        foreach (var item in product.RelatedProducts)
            if (item != this && relatedSet.Add(item))
                GetRelatedProducts(item);
    }
}
```

All these methods handle (IMO) optimally the collecting part. The top N part of course is not optimal - **O(N*log(N))** and can be optimized as mentioned in @Amit Kumar's answer, but it would require implementing a missing standard data structure, which is outside the scope of a SO answer.

Comment: @Mhd Why do you think the depth is 2? It's unlimited. Probably you are missing the inner loop enqueu-ing the RelatedProducts of the related product being added.

Comment: Thanks @Ivan, I think this will work for me. I don't know why I was only  thinking about recursive solution

Comment: @Mhd: He uses the queue in place of recursion. The key is the `HashSet` to prevent re-visiting products. You could do much the same thing with a recursive solution.

Comment: @JimMischel, In recursive solution, I have to make relatedSet global or pass it as parameter to recursive method? That's how I can do it?

Comment: @Mhd: Yes. Either of those would work. Although I think the queue solution provided is more clear.

Comment: @JimMischel Absolutely the use of queue is more clear. However, the recursive solution has better performance. As we don't have to maintain a queue of lists of products.

Comment: @Mhd: you don't maintain an *explicit* queue, but you have a potentially very deep call stack. I consider it unlikely that the recursive solution will have better performance.

Comment: @Mhd What's the issue? Not sure what more attention do you need. The collecting part is quite simple and standard. There are not too many implementation options here - either recursive, ether iterative. The recursive could potentially blow up the stack, and the performance should be nearly the same, so I prefer iterative. I could do also with explicit `Stack` and a couple recursive ways, but don't see the point, except you have a special reason, which I would love to know.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using a priority queue(min heap) of fixed size N. Build the priority queue the time you build the list, so after initial build operation, the priority queue will have top N rated products. Subsequent addition/deletion can be done by checking the checking the top element in the priority queue in `O(log(N))`.

Pseudo Code: New element to be Added E

```
while PQ.size < N
     PQ.enqueue(E)
if PQ.size == N
   Etop = PQ.top() < Min heap element >
   if E.rating > Etop.rating 
      PQ.dequeu()
      PQ.enqueue(E)
```

To get the top N elements , just iterate through the PQ.

Answer (score 2):

My solution :

```
public List<Product> GetTopRelatedProducts(int N)
{
     List<Product> visitedProducts = new List<Product>();
     Queue<Product> ProductsQueue = new Queue<Product>();
     visitedProducts.add(this);
     foreach (product prod in relatedProducts)
         if(prod != this) //if a product can't be related to itself then remove this if statement
             ProductsQueue.Enqueue(prod); 

     //for now visitedproducts contains only our main product and ProductsQueue contains the product related to it.


     while (ProductsQueue.count > 0)
     {
          Product p = ProductsQueue.Dequeue();
          visitedProducts.add(p);
          foreach (product prod in p.relatedProducts)
          {
              if( ! visitedProduct.contains(prod) && !ProductsQueue.contains(prod))//if we haven't visited the product already or if it is not in the queue so we are going to visit it.
                  ProductsQueue.Enqueue(prod);
          }

     }
     //now visitedProducts contains all the products that are related (somehow :P) to your first product

     visitedProducts.remove(this);// to remove the main product from the results
     //all what is left to do is to take the top N products.
     return visitedProducts.OrderByDescending(x => x.Rating).Take(N).ToList();
}
```

I tried to make it as simple as possible ;)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to LINQ. First fetch all the data with all your conditions and then at the end just use `.Take(N)`. Your problem will be solved. :)

Comment: No, that doesn't solve the problem at all. "First fetch all the data" is waving your hand over the specific problem he pointed out.